# Unable to locate Attribute with the given name on this ManagedType [unknown]

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have an entity Called

```
public class Customer implements Auditable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "SellerID")
private Long id;

@Embedded
private AuditSection auditSection = new AuditSection();
......
......
}

@Embeddable
public class AuditSection implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1934446958975060889L;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "DateCreated")
  private Date dateCreated;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  @Column(name = "DateModified")
  private Date dateModified;
  ......
  }
```

I am trying to use the criteriaBuilder and Predicates for Searching

```
 predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.notEqual(root.get("modifiedDate"), new Date)));
```

Here I am getting the Exception

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [modifiedDate] on this ManagedType [unknown]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [modifiedDate] on this ManagedType [unknown]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:374) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:256) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:2.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy187.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.sawce.core.service.customer.impl.CustomerEnquiryServiceImpl.findByPagingCriteria(CustomerEnquiryServiceImpl.java:73) ~[sawce-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sawce.core.service.customer.impl.CustomerEnquiryServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8026ffc6.invoke(<generated>) ~[sawce-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:769) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
```

I have referred some of the similar questions but I did not get any solution.

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace of the Exception?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I posted the Exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of the attribute is **dateModified** not **modifiedDate**.

So the code must look like:

```
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder
  .and(criteriaBuilder.notEqual(
       root.get("auditSection").get("dateModified"), new Date)));
```

Comment: I also tried this. but same error 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [dateModified] on this ManagedType [com.test.domain.Customer]

Comment: Oh I't sorry I didn't see that this is an embeddable. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Perfect anyway - I already able to resolved it. Thanks for the reply. @Simon

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error but my mistake is that I send `entity name`    @Column(name = "abc") but when I send variable name it solved my error.